# Painting dark green over dark blue, primer needed

Tags: painting

I am painting a deep darkish blue wall with a dark green (forest green).  I was planning to use valspar's signiture paint which is a "paint and primer", whatever that means.  I am wondering if I should also be painting a actual primer over the blue before doing the green.  The finish of both the current paint and new paint is satin.

Comment: Can always try a small out of the way section and try to see if the colour bleeds though, instead of painting the whole wall first.  Painting dark to dark should cover better than dark to lighter.

Answer (score 3):

So, there are a few reasons to use primer on already finished walls.

1. The current paint is gloss and new paint would not stick well
2. The current paint is dark and needs covered for a light color going over top of it (straight primer is normally a good bit cheaper than paint; like $30/ga vs $60-45/ga)
3. You have stains that need extra attention to cover.

In your case, your paint/primer should be fine without a separate primer coat because you are painting over a satin finish with a dark color. Just be sure to clean the wall before painting even if you just wipe it down with a barely damp microfiber cloth/sponge.

Comment: Kitchen or bathroom walls would probably could do with a better cleaning, maybe even using TSP to remove grease/oils.

Comment: @crip659 I agree. but I am a bit excessive in all my wall prep. I clean with TSP, wipe with damp microfiber. fill/patch, sand, dust mop, dust mop again, prime, paint. If I were painting a mural, I'd probably just wipe down with a TSP solution and after with a plain water dampened microfiber cloth.

Comment: Guess I know who to call next time I feel like painting.  Too bad I probably can't afford you.

Comment: @crip659 I always get grief from my better half about taking so long to repaint a room.

Comment: But the paint job lasts.

Comment: Gloss is also going to require scuff sanding.  Really it's just a good idea all around. And cleaning of course, you can't just plop primer onto ??? surface.

Comment: For the transpondians, UK usually uses [sugar soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_soap) which I thought might just be a different name for the same thing, but apparently not. It is equally good at cleaning paintwork, & does provide something of a key on gloss paint.